# Google Calendar API NodeJS - specify fields

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

Heyo, I'm using the [google-api-nodejs-client](https://npmjs.org/package/googleapis) package in my NodeJS project and I'm trying to build my query for calendar events. It's working, but I can't specify the "fields" field.

This returns five complete calendar events:

```
client.calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: gcal_id,
    maxResults: 5
})
.withAuthClient(authClient)
.execute(function(err, calendar) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log(calendar);
});
```

But this returns nothing:

```
client.calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: gcal_id,
    maxResults: 5,
    fields: {
        items: ["end","start","status","summary"]
    }
})
.withAuthClient(authClient)
.execute(function(err, calendar) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log(calendar);
});
```

I've also tried:

```
fields: {
    items: "end,start,status,summary"
}
```

Based on the Google Calendar V3 API, I should be able to make a query like this:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/gcal_id.google.com/events?maxResults=5&fields=items(end%2Cstart%2Cstatus%2Csummary)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

I'm not sure how to specify the "fields=items(end%2Cstart%2Cstatus%2Csummary)" portion of the URL, but I've tested it in Google's API Explorer and it works, so I know I'm doing something wrong in the JavaScript.

Any help would be much appreciated. For now I think I'll just clean up the response I get from the first code snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. It should be one string.

```
fields: "items(end,start,status,summary)"
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that as of Mar 6, 2017, if you specify ```fields```, it will ONLY return the fields specified. For example, if you pass ```"items(summary)"```, only summary gets returned for every item.